# How can I change text color in a Semantic UI vertical menu?

Tags: html, css, pug, semantic-ui

I have an active red link item in a vertical menu and I only want the pointer to be red.  What is the most effective way to change the text so it is black? I have attempted to wrap it in a paragraph element but that only makes it difficult to reposition.

[image]

Comment: very difficult question with such little information!

Comment: What other sort of information is necessary?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can use this: **class="ui red header"**

http://semantic-ui.com/elements/header.html#colors

Answer (score 3):

The code for that would look something like this

```
<div class="ui vertical menu">
  <a class="home">
    HOME
  </a>
</div>
```

Your css would have to look something like this with your desired color

```
a.home {
    color: red;
    ...
}
```

Comment: There's no tag specified in the documentation for a link item.  It's just 

    <div class="ui vertical menu">HOME</div> -- Are you suggesting I wrap it in a link tag?